# use output from previous pipeline run in current pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to get some output from the same pipeline that was run previously.

Suppose in run *my-pipeline* which outputs some *hash*. Next time I run this pipeline, I want to get the *hash* from the previous run of *my-pipeline*.

The reason for that is essentially conditional cache invalidation, So sometimes I need to reuse the same generated hash, while other times I want to generate a new hash that from then on is passed down each pipeline run, until it's changed again.

Answer (score 0):

To transfer output between different pipeline runs, typically we will consider artifacts or store output somewhere which will be not deleted.

According to your description, you can put the hash value to a file and push to your repo in the pipeline, when you check it out in the next pipeline run, you can read from the file to get the value.You can also add tag value to hint it's changed or not.